# Manual loaded module don't have all attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-importlib

I do manual loading of the module `requests`. I do it twice in a row, one by one, in the same manner. The module is installed and located in default `site-packages`. The script is:

```
specification = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
    name='requests',
    location='/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py',
)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec=specification)
sys.modules[module.__name__] = module
specification.loader.exec_module(module=module)

requests = module
print(requests)
print(len(dir(requests)))
print(requests.api)

print()
print()

specification = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
    name='requests',
    location='/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py',
)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec=specification)
sys.modules[module.__name__] = module
specification.loader.exec_module(module=module)

requests = module
print(requests)
print(len(dir(requests)))
print(requests.api)
```

The output is the following one:

```
module 'requests' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'>
66
<module 'requests.api' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py'>


module 'requests' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'>
53
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    print(requests.api)
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'api'
```

If I take a look at the `dir`'s responses, the first one will have many more attributes than the second one. For instance, `api` attribute is presented in the first module but isn't in the second one.

I tried (any of them doesn't work):

- `globals()[module.__name__] = module` after each loading.
- `del sys.modules[module.__name__]` before and after each loading.

What I missed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `import requests` imports the package `requests` (which includes other modules). Your `importlib` only creates a new module based on the file `requests/__init__.py`, which is *not* the same as the package `requests`.

Comment: @chepner, but why then my first import has the same attributes as I do `import requests; print(len(dir(requests)))` if I import it with `importlib`?

Comment: Some attributes of the `requests` package are set directly inside `__init__.py`; `api` is not one of them. `__init__.py` uses `from .api import *`, thus importing and reimporting all the names defined in `api.py` but not exporting the name `api` itself.

Comment: What benefit do you think you are getting by loading `requests/__init__.py` manually? (Or are you just experimenting with how `importlib` works?)

Comment: But why the result is different from above's two same importing though `importlib`. I understand your answer as the answer for the different questions (what is the different beet just import and importlib).

Comment: @chepner, I just play with the library.

Comment: OK, I'll leave my comment as-is rather than posting as an answer, as I'm not sure it's precisely correct. (If this was for real code, I would simply say "Stop using `import lib` and just use `import requests`".)